# Why Opportunity object has special features than others

Tags: apex, relationships, master-detail

I need a little explanation on Opportunity object. I was wondering Account and opportunity objects are in Lookup Relation but acting as Master-Detail. Also in workflows, we can update Account Records from Opportunity even though workflows are not meant to update child records... Can someone please explain to me why the Opportunity object is special than others...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: I'm not sure Opportunity is "special". Updating Account from Opportunity change event through a workflow is completely normal. Account is a parent record regarding Opportunity which means for 1 opportunity you have only 1 account so updating is perfectly fine here.

Comment: Is there something that I missed ?

Comment: Yes, 1 opportunity will have 1 account. But, why the relation between Account and Opportunity seems like Master-Detail...

Comment: What makes you think it is like Master-Detail ? From my point of view, Salesforce is known to have weird hidden specificity on "standard" part. So I wouldn't be surprised that this relation might be special. If you give more detail I can probably help you understand.

Comment: When I delete the account record the related opportunities will be deleted. It's possible only in master-detail relation. But in the workflow, we are able to update account records from opportunity. If the relation is Lookup how it is possible...

Comment: Indeed this is an hidden standard behavior. Some lookup relationship still have the ability to delete child records when parent is deleted which is only available for Master-Detail on the custom part (by default). They are several standard objects that behave like that. You can find that by getting the [childRelationships of an object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship.htm#apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship)